# Close Tab after clicking on item Template in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I don't want to open the Page tab after clicking on Item Template. I want users to double click the items in solution explorer to open in tab. Can anyone suggest how to do through code?

Comment: Code? Do you mean with addin? It's just a setting then it can be exported and imported.

Comment: code is not required. I just want not to open the tab.

Comment: It's a setting. No Vs on mobile but search, it's there (**auto preview** or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

In RunFinished() method you have to write

ProjectItem.Document.Close();

and this is what I needed.

Comment: Hmmmmm my fault but I cannot understand how this is related in any way to your own question! If this was what you had to do please update question too...